# How to map one word to another word in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

how can I map a word to another word in Elasticsearch?. That is suppose I have the following data document

```
{
"carName" : "Porche"
"review": " this car is so awesome"
}
```

Now when I search good/fantastic etc, it should map to "awesome".
Is there any way I can do this in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this by using a [synonym token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html).

First you need to define a new custom analyzer in your index and use that analyzer in your mapping.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/cars -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "synonyms"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "synonyms": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "good, awesome, fantastic"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "car": {
      "properties": {
        "carName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "review": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

You can add as many synonyms as you want, either in the settings directly or in a separate file that you can reference in the settings using the `synonyms_path` property.

Then we can index your sample document above:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/cars/car/1 -d '{
  "carName": "Porche",
  "review": " this car is so awesome"
}'
```

What is going to happen is that when the `synonyms` token filter kicks in, it will also index the tokens `good` and `fantastic` along with `awesome` so that you can search and find that document by those tokens as well. Concretely, analyzing the sentence `this car is so awesome`...

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/cars/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty' -d 'this car is so awesome'
```

...will produce the following tokens (see the last three tokens)

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "this",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "car",
    "start_offset" : 5,
    "end_offset" : 8,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "is",
    "start_offset" : 9,
    "end_offset" : 11,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "so",
    "start_offset" : 12,
    "end_offset" : 14,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 4
  }, {
    "token" : "good",
    "start_offset" : 15,
    "end_offset" : 22,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 5
  }, {
    "token" : "awesome",
    "start_offset" : 15,
    "end_offset" : 22,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 5
  }, {
    "token" : "fantastic",
    "start_offset" : 15,
    "end_offset" : 22,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 5
  } ]
}
```

Finally, you can search like this and the document will be retrieved:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/cars/car/_search?q=review:good
```